# Http Delete request to django returns a 301(Moved permenantly)

Tags: django, rest

When I do a Http DELETE request to a django app. it directly returns a 301(Moved permanantly) response and redirects me to GET request of same url. I am guessing that Http PUT request would return 301 just like DELETE request. Is there any way to process DELETE request with django?

Comment: Is it possible you are missing the trailing slash in the url for the DELETE?

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not the relevant view is being loaded at all? Maybe put a log inside the view to confirm it is being loaded. Also, could this be your web server and not Django at all that is redirecting the request?

Comment: That was the problem. My client is backbone.js and it seems like backbone.js does not put trailing slash to model urls. so in urls.py, I added another url configuration without trailing slash and it worked.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The redirect is caused by the [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-APPEND_SLASH) setting:

> **APPEND_SLASH**
>
> Default: True
>
> When set to True, if the request URL
>   does not match any of the patterns in
>   the URLconf and it doesn't end in a
>   slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to
>   the same URL with a slash appended.
>   Note that the redirect may cause any
>   data submitted in a POST request to be
>   lost.

Make sure your server and client are consistent with trailing slashes.

If your project does not need the trailing slashes at all (i.e., it is an api without trailing slashes) you can disable it.  Otherwise, make sure your urlconf accept paths without a trailing slash.

Comment: This option has been configured for the $resource component from angularJS 1.30.beta6 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3878be52f6d95fca4c386d4a5523f3c8fcb04270

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue while using AngularJs and Django REST.

Django Rest was redirecting the client in order to request the URL with a trailing slash while AngularJS' `$resource` ensures there is not a trailing dash on its URLs. This is described in this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/992#ref-issue-15036520)

On the same link you will see suggestions to use the more flexible `$http` service instead of `$resource`. But... I really wanted to use `$resource` (less code).

So the solution was trivial, since the Django REST team have accounted for this [recently](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/commit/f1251e8c58e86db11028396d79f01db5dfcf9e52):

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
```

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers.html

(I've added to this to my [blog](http://www.megustaulises.com/2013/07/angularjs-and-django-rest.html) since I'd like to keep a log of a few gotchas using AngularJS & Django REST)

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that might cause this is when your web server redirects `http` requests to `https` and your frontend client is sending a request to `http`. This was the case for me. So change the client to call `https` directly.