# Enable Django and Tastypie support for trailing slashes?

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, tastypie

My problem is that Backbone is trying to do an HTTP request on a URL with a slash at the end, like the following:

```
:8000/api/v1/update/2/
```

For some reason, Django (or tastypie) is not accepting URLs with slashes at the end, so the above URL will not work, but this URL does work:

```
:8000/api/v1/update/2
```

Backbone-tastypie falls back to oldSync, which is the original sync that comes with Backbone, when not using its overridden sync. I believe that when Backbone-tastypie uses oldSync, it appends a slash at the end of the URLs, which I do not want.

Most of the solutions being suggested are dealing with the opposite problem I have. They are trying to fix the problem where trailing slashes work, but no trailing slashes do not work.

I need to be able to support trailing slashes in addition to non-trailing slashes. This can be fixed in two ways:

1. How do I change the backbone-tastypie code so that no AJAX calls append the slash at the end?
2. How do I make it so that Django/tastypie will treat the above two URLs as the same?

Either one of those will fix my problem, but I cannot figure out how to implement any of them.

Comment: Have you looked at this module? https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891879/http-delete-request-to-django-returns-a-301moved-permenantly

Comment: @thedjpetersen I am using Paul's backbone-tastypie right now. It works up until backbone-tastypie uses Backbone.sync because the default URL has a slash appended to the end. I have the opposite problem of the link that fguillen posted. I am only able to support URLs without slashes appended to the end. In the link above, it seems like they only support URLs with slashes at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't understand: do you want slashes at the end of the URLs or not?.

Comment: @fguillen I do not want slashes at the end of the URLs. When Backbone uses oldSync, it makes an HTTP request to a URL that has a slash at the end. Unfortunately, Django (or Tastypie) doesn't like when a URL has a slash at the end. I'll put more details in the body of the original post.

Comment: But as far I can see [in the code](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L434-438) Backbone doesn't add slashes at the end :?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `Backbone` solution:

You can overwrite the default behavior of `Model.url`, even using the normal one and making a small modification like the one you are looking for:

```
// code simplified and not tested
var MyModel: Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    var original_url = Backbone.Model.prototype.url.call( this );
    var parsed_url = original_url + ( original_url.charAt( original_url.length - 1 ) == '/' ? '' : '/' );

    return parsed_url;
  }
});
```

Same aplies for `Collection`.

Comment: I think the problem has more to do with the default sync behavior of Backbone. My urls in my collections and models do not have slashes at the end. When backbone-tastypie uses the default Backbone sync, it tries to do an HTTP request on a link like: :8000/api/v1/update/2/ when it tries to sync. When I delete a model instance in Backbone, the initial delete call works well because it calls the URL that is specified in the model. But, then it tries to use Backbone.oldSync, which is the original sync method. For some reason, the sync appends a slash to the end.

Answer (score 7):

You can tell Tastypie/Django to allow or disallow trailing slashes.

Look [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#tastypie-allow-missing-slash)

Comment: I think this is more of a Backbone problem than Tastypie. I still get an error because I am making an AJAX call to a URL that ends with a slash. Tastypie (or Django) does not like URLs with a slash, so I get an error when I make a request to the URL with a slash at the end. How do I make it so Tastypie accepts URLs with slashes at the end because right now it does not. It only accepts URLs without slashes at the end.

Comment: I just told you. If you set `TASTYPIE_ALLOW_MISSING_SLASH = False` and `APPEND_SLASH = True` Django\Tastypie URLs will be with slashes at the end.