# Remove Confirmation box on backbone PUT and DELETE request to django api on firefox

Tags: javascript, django, jquery, firefox, backbone.js

Firefox is showing a confirmation box when a PUT or DELETE request is going from backbone to django rest api, whereas no such confirmation being asked for POST request.

> This web page is being redirected to a new location. Would you like to resend the form data you have typed to the new location?

In chrome no such confirmation box coming.

Is there any way to remove this box? what would be the reason for it?

Comment: Please help me anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the django rest framework.

include following in urls.py

> router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)

by default trailing_slash = true
Now its working fine

You can find more details here:

> [Http Delete request to django returns a 301(Moved permenantly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891879/http-delete-request-to-django-returns-a-301moved-permenantly)