# How to delete a calendar collection RFC 6638

Tags: caldav

- I am trying to delete entire user calendar as part of user wanting to delete account.
- I am trying to use following URLS to delete an `event and calendar resource`. The **delete event URL works** but the **calendar URL does not**.
- I am getting `URLDomain` error.

  ```
   #define kEventURLFormat                         @"/calendars/users/%@/calendar/%@.ics"

   #define kCalendarCollectionURLFormat            @"/calendars/users/%@/calendar"
  ```
- RFC 6638 mentions the following.

3.2.3.2.  DELETE

When the server receives a DELETE method request targeted at a
scheduling object resource, it MUST execute the Remove operation.

When the server receives a DELETE method request targeted at a
calendar collection, it MUST execute the Remove operation on all
scheduling object resources contained in the calendar collection.

---

### **What URL should I be using to delete entire USER calendar?**

Comment: I get following output: curl -k --user "user1:pwd" -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8" "http://example.com:8008/calendars/users/user1/calendar"                            
 
<html><head><title>Moved Permanently</title></head><body><h1>Moved Permanently</h1><p>Document moved to http://example.com:8008/calendars/users/user1/calendar/.</p></body></html>%

Comment: why the negative vote? Is it because I asked something wrong on SO or is it because I am doing something wrong in caldav/calendaring context?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct URL

```
#define kCalendarCollectionURLFormat            @"/calendars/users/%@/calendar/"
```

[Http Delete request to django returns a 301(Moved permenantly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891879/http-delete-request-to-django-returns-a-301moved-permenantly)